# Twitter API wrong rate-limit for users/lookup using oAuth

Tags: api, twitter, lookup, rate-limiting

i'm trying to get the users/lookup for about 400 users using oAuth. The result data is ok but when i check the rate limit it was based on ip rather than oAuth.
I've checked the oAuth credentials with "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml" and the result is ok. 
Someone experience the same issue?

P.S. getting home timeline tweets uses the correct rate limit.

Thanks!
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that the commas between users ids was not urlencrypted. Encrypting or replacing them with %2C solves the problem